# Prevent record deletion with SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I want to prevent a record from being deleted based on certain conditions in NetSuite.  However, I can't seem to find a failure event on validation?  BeforeSubmit on a UserEvent has a delete **type**, but it doesn't have a return value for the function, so I can't just say return false, can I?

How do I then prevent the deletion of a record, or *fail* a record submission of a certain type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of returning false, just throw an error.  Not user friendly but it is the only option, as far as I know.

Since it is in the Before Submit User Event, the submission or deletion will fail.

Comment: Yep this will do it. The only way to halt a record from being stored in the database during a User Event script is to throw an Error from `beforeSubmit`.

Comment: What would be the safest (best practice?) way to do this?  The Throw function?  I've never used it before, but it looks like it would be the correct solution?

Comment: throw function would be the correct solution.  You can also use nlapiCreateError in SuiteScript 1.0 to create your custom error.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a `beforeSubmit` user event script and throw an error using `nlapiCreateError`. Here's an example:

```
function beforeSubmit(type) {
  if(type == 'delete') {
    // NOTE `nlapiGetFieldValue` returns nil/empty during a delete event
    //      `nlapiGetOldRecord` needs to be used to pull the entire record

    var payment = nlapiGetOldRecord();

    if(payment.getFieldText('paymentmethod') == 'cash') {
      throw nlapiCreateError(
        'AN_ERROR',
        'Message to the user!',
        true
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a Workflow to prevent the **Delete** button to display to the user:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add client-side code to pop up a message to the user when trying to delete a record you want to prevent.  With that said, you would still want to put a UserEvent script preventing the delete actions as well.  This would prevent the user from by passing the restriction

Comment: What event on the client side would do this?  I did initially look at it, and my current 'plan' for if things failed was to simply redirect the user automatically back to the View record if they tried to edit it, but I didn't see a client event type that would register the 'delete' type